# How to wait until four different methods finishes and then execute another different method in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

i have a Android app and this is my problem.

my application have **4 methods**, each method upload a diferent file to Firebase Storage, **after all the four previous methods were executed i want to execute another method**, but all the methods executes at the same time and don't works how its have to be, so i want to know how to make that the four methods be executed one by one(wait that the previous method ends and continue with another), thanks

Here is how i call the methods:

```
private void putFiles(){

putImage();
putCoverImage();
putPDF();
putPDF2();

//i want execute this method after all the previous methods were executed
showAlertDialog();

}
```

a example of how files are uploaded

```
private void putPDF() {

    if (pdfUri != null) {
        final StorageReference fileReference = storagePermisos.child("pdf").child(String.valueOf(ID));

        fileReference.child(name).child("file." + getFileExtension(pdfUri)).delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


                fileReference.child(edtName.getText().toString()).child("file." + getFileExtension(tributarioUri)).putFile(tributarioUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        fileReference.child(nombre.getText().toString()).child("file." + getFileExtension(tributarioUri)).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                linkPdf.setText(String.valueOf(uri));
                            }
                        })
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                        myRef.child("files").child(String.valueOf(ID)).child("pdf").setValue(linkPdf.getText().toString());
                                        
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                // a toast
                            }
                        });
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: Can you share how you are calling these methods? Or some code that's in these methods? Please show a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You say "after all the previous were fully executed"; do those functions spawn other threads or otherwise run things in parallel? If not, then the code already does what you desire (so I assume these fns do spawn threads or similar). Please edit your question and add some more code so we can help with the specifics

Comment: i show how i call these methods, i'm new in this so i don't know how threads works

Comment: I see; can you share some example of what's in the `put*` functions? I don't think we can answer the question further without that info.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of when CompletableFuture can be used. You have 4 tasks that can be run in parallel and completed anytime asynchronously without mutating each other or depending on each other. This uses the CompletableFuture internal `ForkJoinPool#commonPool` or a `thread-per-task` model. You can opt to use your own ExecutorService if you want.

```java
        CompletableFuture<Void> putAll = CompletableFuture.allOf(
                        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::putImage),
                        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::putCoverImage),
                        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::putPDF),
                        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::putPDF2))
                .thenRunAsync(this::showAlertDialog);
        
        putAll.join();
```

Comment: i got this error "no suitable method found for supplyAsync(this::putImage)
method CompletableFuture.<U#1>supplyAsync(Supplier<U#1>) is not applicable"

Comment: i executed this and dont solved my problem but thanks, the methods stills executingg all at the same time